# Issue with Apache Camel with CXF SOAP service

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

Flow is not going to the implementation class at all. How should get the flow to Implementation class?
I wonder if it doesn't matter that Impl class `implements` the service class.
 But it raises another question what if more than one impl classes are implementing the serviceClass interface. Where the flow will go?
Do I need to declare some annotations on Impl class? Or there is no way to recognize Impl class, I just have to treat it as another bean and add it to my webservice route.
Here is the setup.
**applicationContext.xml**

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="tryWebService" address="http://localhost:15080/PORTAL/webservices/tryWebService"
            serviceClass="webservice.TryWebServiceImpl"
            />
        <route>
            <from uri="cxf:bean:tryWebService"/>
            <to uri="stream:out"/>
        </route>
```

**Interface**

```
@WebService
public interface TryWebService {
    public void acceptRequest(String xmlString);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class ACORDWebServiceImpl implements ACORDWebService
{
    public void acceptTXLife(String xmlString)
    {
        try
        {
            dosomething
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service class in cxf is only an interface. You d'ont need implementation. Parameters of the method called ( ie: "acceptRequest") are set in the body of your route.  So you can get them in the route with a processor for example between your from and to instructions.

Comment: Then how would I get to the method implementation?

Comment: why would you do this ? in camel logical process you should retrieve your parameters in a route

Comment: Do you mean that from `<from uri="cxf:bean:tryWebService"/>` I should take it to implementation bean itself? Interface is just a way to receive the parameters. Can you please suggest me some code example?

Comment: Are you really sure that you need to use camel for this? If you just need to call the ACORDWebServiceImpl implementation, then I think that it would be better to use it as a plain cxf service.

Comment: I'm agree with alexander, i think in your case a cxf endpoint bound to the ACORDWebServiceImpl  (which implements your interface) should be sufficient